# Get post result with cURL and PHP

Tags: php, curl, forms

I have a little function which performs a form submission and it should return the result (html).

The form has only one text input:

```
<input type="text" value="" maxlength="5" name="CODE" size="10">
```

This is how I try to fill this variable with cURL:

```
//open connection
$ch = curl_init();

$myValue = "Test123";
$formUrl = "http://www.mywebsite.com/post.php";

//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $formUrl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 120);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 120);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "CODE=".$myValue);

//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);

//close connection
curl_close($ch);

echo $result;
```

My problem is that I don't get any results... Is there any problem with this code?

Thank you very much for the help!

EDIT:

I also tried with this kind of setup, with the same result:

```
$formData = array('CHKCODE' => $tesseractOutput);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $formUrl);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 120);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 120);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($formData));
```

Comment: Try to use following syntax `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, ["CODE" => $myValue]);`

Comment: I tried, sadly it's the same :(

Answer (score 0):

You could try a bit different approach. [A simple example:](http://www.lornajane.net/posts/2009/putting-data-fields-with-php-curl)

```
    $data = array("CODE" => "Test123");
    //$ch = curl_init("http://www.mywebsite.com/post.php");
    //EDIT
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
    //EDIT
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.mywebsite.com/post.php");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,http_build_query($data));

    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    var_dump($response);
    curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: I get with the "customrequest" option this error: "Method PUT denied by policy"